# Turn off/on underscore for statements across multiple lines in VS 2015 for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS 2015 and some of my team members are using VS 2013. In VS 2015, we do not require "underscore" (_) to indicate statement across multiple lines. Is there a way to turn it off in VS 2015 ?

Comment: Implicit line continuations was a new feature in VS2010.

Comment: Are you thinking of multi-line strings, rather than statement continuation?

Comment: I am looking for both of them

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874556/prevent-visual-studio-2015-from-removing-line-continuation-characters-in-vb