# How to prevent visual studio 2017 from removing underscore (_) in vb code with continuation characters

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have an old VB.Net project where I'm contributor and for compatibility reasons I need to keep underscore continuation characters where they are at code but Visual Studio 2017 is removing those.

For example:

```
Cache.Add(
    "cacheErr", _
    objArray, _
    Nothing, _
    Date.Today.AddHours(1), _
    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, _
    System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, _
    Nothing)
```

When I open the file and change some of code the underscores are removed like this:

```
Cache.Add(
    "cacheErrDispensacion", 
    objArray, 
    Nothing, 
    Date.Today.AddHours(1), 
    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, 
    System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, 
    Nothing)
```

As a result, this can not compile at older versions of visual studio.

I would like to know if there is a configuration to prevent this behaviour with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Actually, they would have to be very, *very* old versions - implicit line continuation goes back to *at least* 2012.  I dont think it can be disabled.  You may need to get an ancient copy, or the others could get a newer version

Comment: Haha @Plutonix you make it sound like they are from antiquity.

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874556/prevent-visual-studio-2015-from-removing-line-continuation-characters-in-vb?rq=1) about VS 2015 recommends disabling the "Pretty listing" option of the text editor.

Comment: There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874556/prevent-visual-studio-2015-from-removing-line-continuation-characters-in-vb) which may be worth a look at.

Comment: @Plutonix you are right! hahaha... It is an ancient code made with vs2003 Pre-release I think. Framework 1.1